# Check if RecyclerView is scrollable is not working fine for me

Tags: android

I have to check if the `RecyclerView` is able to `layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()` always returns `-1` for me .This is my code. I refer it form [Check if RecyclerView is scrollable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32747471/check-if-recyclerview-is-scrollable)

```
 private void setAdapterData() {
        mChatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(mMessagesList);
        mChatMessagesRecyclerView.setAdapter(mChatAdapter);
        boolean ss=isRecyclerScrollable();
        Log.e("ss",ss+""+mMessagesList.size()+"ll");
    }

    public boolean isRecyclerScrollable() {
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mChatMessagesRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();

        if (layoutManager == null || mChatAdapter == null) return false;
        Log.e("ss",layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() +"ll");
        return layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() < mChatAdapter.getItemCount() - 1;
```

}

My actual code is

```
private void setAdapterData() {
        mChatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(mMessagesList);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        mChatMessagesRecyclerView.setAdapter(mChatAdapter);
        if(isRecyclerScrollable())
            mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        mChatMessagesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    }
    public boolean isRecyclerScrollable() {

            RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = mChatMessagesRecyclerView.getAdapter();
            if (mLayoutManager == null || adapter == null) return false;

            return mLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() < adapter.getItemCount() - 1;
        }
```

I am actually looking answer for this question

[set setStackFromEnd parameter to recycler view based on some condition check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41390862/set-setstackfromend-parameter-to-recycler-view-based-on-some-condition-check)

my current working code is

```
if(mMessagesList.size()>5)
                    setStackFromEndLayoutManager();
                setAdapterData();

private void setStackFromEndLayoutManager() {
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        mChatMessagesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    }
```

i hard coded here mMessagesList.size()>5  ... i have to make it as dynamic..so i looking for answer  Check if RecyclerView is scrollable??/

Comment: where are you setting layout manager?

Comment: Set layout manager to your recycler view

Comment: Set layout manager before calling isScrollable method

Comment: Why you are creating a new layout manager object in setStackFromEndLayoutManager(). Just create and set it as soon as you are creating RecyclerView object. No need to set is again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37113812/recyclerview-linearlayout-manager-always-returns-1-in-landscape-mode-findlast is this relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this **setAdapterData()**.
 And call this before all other things.

```
private void setAdapterData() {
    mChatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(mMessagesList);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    mChatMessagesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mChatMessagesRecyclerView.setAdapter(mChatAdapter);

    if(isRecyclerScrollable())
        mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

}
public boolean isRecyclerScrollable() {
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = mChatMessagesRecyclerView.getAdapter();
        if (mLayoutManager == null || adapter == null) return false;
            return mLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() < adapter.getItemCount() - 1;
}
```

And you don't need **setStackFromEndLayoutManager()** method

Comment: isRecyclerScrollable() is always return true....this not working..even with the single item it returns true

Comment: int visibleItemCount = mLinearLayoutManager.getChildCount();
if(visibleItemCount < adapter.getItemCount()){ return true;}
use this logic

Comment: mLayoutManager.getChildCount() returns 0

Comment: getChildCount() returns the count of items attached to recyclerView. It means no data is attached to your view yet. Try using `viewTreeObserver`

Comment: ya it works thanks for answer...but still i wondering why it takes time  to attach data??

Comment: :) Views takes time Because there are so many calculations (for example calculation of height/width) that need to be performed to render it.

Answer (score 0):

hii please add following code in CalladapterMethod

```
private void setAdapterData() {
    mChatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(mMessagesList);
    mChatMessagesRecyclerView.setAdapter(mChatAdapter);
    boolean ss=isRecyclerScrollable();
    Log.e("ss",ss+""+mMessagesList.size()+"ll");
mChartAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code,
You are setting

```
mChatMessagesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

after your condition check where you are looking for

```
mLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
```

if your condition `if(mMessagesList.size()>5)` is false, the layout manager is not set in the recyclerview and it will not have any visible items.Set it before the condition.

Comment: actually my expectation is to replace if(mMessagesList.size()>5) this condition because it is static instead i have to make the funactional call like this

Comment: public boolean isRecyclerScrollable() {
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mChatMessagesRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();

        if (layoutManager == null || mChatAdapter == null) return false;
        Log.e("ss",layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() +"ll");
        return layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() < mChatAdapter.getItemCount() - 1;

Comment: But it not works well ....layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()  always return -1

Comment: because you are setting that layout manager to recyclerview after condition check..so it cant find your items..set the layout manager to your recyclerview before the isScrollable method is called